# Missing Location header on jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm performing an AJAX POST with jQuery like so:

```
self.post = function (path, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: this.createUri(path),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ko.toJSON(data)
    });
};
```

Here I just return the AJAX Deferred object. The response is handled by another object:

```
api.post(menuItemsUri, self.newItem)
    .done(function (data, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader("Location")); // undefined
    })
    .always(function () {
        // reset the current item
        self.newItem.update({});
    });
```

The server returns a `201 Created` Response and sets the Location header. I can see this in the Chrome Network tab:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 07 Feb 2013 10:25:04 GMT
Expires:-1
Location:http://localhost:49978/sites/1/menus/65/items/19
Pragma:no-cache
```

However, the Location header is missing from the `XmlHttpRequest` object passed in the jQuery AJAX callback.

Comment: Have your tried outputting the result of `getAllResponseHeaders()` to see what's in it?

Comment: Yes: `Pragma, Cache-Control, Expires`.

Comment: Well I think perhaps that you can't send a location header, perhaps due to the nature of how an xmlhttprequest works. It might not be able to follow a location header, therefore it could either be ignored or not even sent. Not sure. Could you not just set a new header called something like `New-Location` and read that? Obviously  that isn't ideal though.

Answer (score 15):

The issue was that this was a CORS request and according to the [CORS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors) only the following "Simple Response Headers" are exposed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

To expose additional headers you need to include them in the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header) header e.g.:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: location
```

Once this change was made, the Location header was available to the XmlHttpRequest object via `getResponseHeader("Location")`.

For normal (non-CORS) requests, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually adding the location header, or expecting it to automagically be returned by the server script? As it may not actually be set.
Unless you are redirecting I would expect that it would not be set, and Chrome might actually just be adding it itself to be "helpful".

Maybe just try explicitly setting the location header in your script, then it should definitely be there, but that might have undesired side-effects.

Comment: The Location header is explicitly set by the API. How would Chrome know what to set the header to if it wasn't included in the response.